Why is a clean Maven project in Netbeans not running
I am setting up a local instance to run a Java webapp. It's been a while since I've done this but I've done it in the past. So far what I've done is installed JDK 22.0.2 and Netbeans 22 on my local machine. I've created a new Netbeans project Java with Maven Web Application. For my server I have Apache Tomcat 9 installed and I'm selecting Jakarta EE 8 Web for my Java EE version, I'm assuming that is the latest but here is a screenshot of all the available options.

After this I click finish and let the new project get created. Just to make sure everything works I run the project but I'm getting the following error.

BUILD FAILURE
Total time:  24.932 s
Finished at: 2024-07-26T11:26:49-04:00
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.3:war (default-war) on project UnitConverter: Execution default-war of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.3:war failed: Unable to load the mojo 'war' in the plugin 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.3' due to an API incompatibility: org.codehaus.plexus.component.repository.exception.ComponentLookupException: null
realm =    plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.3
strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
urls[0] = file:/C:/Users/LauXi/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-war-plugin/2.3/maven-war-plugin-2.3.jar
urls1 = file:/C:/Users/LauXi/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/reporting/maven-reporting-api/2.0.6/maven-reporting-api-2.0.6.jar
urls[2] = file:/C:/Users/LauXi/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-sink-api/1.0-alpha-7/doxia-sink-api-1.0-alpha-7.jar
urls[3] = file:/C:/Users/LauXi/.m2/repository/commons-cli/commons-cli/1.0/commons-cli-1.0.jar
urls[4] = file:/C:/Users/LauXi/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-interactivity-api/1.0-alpha-4/plexus-interactivity-api-1.0-alpha-4.jar
urls[5] = file:/C:/Users/LauXi/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/maven-archiver/2.5/maven-archiver-2.5.jar
urls[6] = file:/C:/Users/LauXi/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-io/2.0.5/plexus-io-2.0.5.jar
urls[7] = file:/C:/Users/LauXi/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-archiver/2.2/plexus-archiver-2.2.jar
urls[8] = file:/C:/Users/LauXi/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-interpolation/1.15/plexus-interpolation-1.15.jar
urls[9] = file:/C:/Users/LauXi/.m2/repository/junit/junit/3.8.1/junit-3.8.1.jar
urls[10] = file:/C:/Users/LauXi/.m2/repository/com/thoughtworks/xstream/xstream/1.4.3/xstream-1.4.3.jar
urls[11] = file:/C:/Users/LauXi/.m2/repository/xmlpull/xmlpull/1.1.3.1/xmlpull-1.1.3.1.jar
urls[12] = file:/C:/Users/LauXi/.m2/repository/xpp3/xpp3_min/1.1.4c/xpp3_min-1.1.4c.jar
urls[13] = file:/C:/Users/LauXi/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/3.0.8/plexus-utils-3.0.8.jar
urls[14] = file:/C:/Users/LauXi/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-filtering/1.0-beta-2/maven-filtering-1.0-beta-2.jar
Number of foreign imports: 1
import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]

: ExceptionInInitializerError: Unable to make field private final java.util.Comparator java.util.TreeMap.comparator accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.util" to unnamed module @1dd64243
-> [Help 1]
To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginContainerException
I've been reading a lot of posts and articles but nothing that seems to know why this would be occurring with a brand new project. Any ideas would be much appreciated.

I pasted your error into Google.  It found this.  It may be the solution to your problem.  NetBeans?  Really?  https://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-frameworks/jboss-maven/solving-unable-to-load-the-mojo-war-in-the-plugin/

Only BalusC's (https://stackoverflow.com/users/157882/balusc) answer is correct and perfect, other answers will be deducted.

You can remove all build block, <build>....</build> from pom.xml

No Tomcat 9 and Jakarta EE 8 are not the latest, far from it. The latest are Tomcat 10.1 and Jakarta EE 10, with Tomcat 11.0 and Jakarta EE 11 nearly done. Tomcat 9 is still supported/maintained however.

Please upgrade all plugins you are using. You are using ancient old version of maven-war-plugin (https://maven.apache.org/plugins/) ...

I've already commented on 2 answers that the Maven WAR plugin version being used (2.3) is super old (and thus logically the OP just either need to upgrade Maven in his system or explicitly bump the Maven WAR plugin version via pom.xml). The answers were deleted instead of edited. Guys, downvotes are not irreversible and I always comment them and always revert them when the answer is fixed. Just fix the answer based on the comment.

When my answer already mentioned changing the version of war plugin to a newer version, who commented it as downvotes? Please. When you feel that only your answer is correct. Others' answers are wrong. No need to raise unnecessary points False explanation. Besides, it’s 2024 and we are still advocating the use of JDK 8? Is this the standard and correct answer?

At the same time, my answer also mentioned you can remove all build block (<build>...</build>). If you do not set the war plugin, Maven will apply the current version of the war plugin. Of course, this The answer was also ignored by someone and deemed wrong, you must write: The only problem is the maven war plugin 2.3 which is super old (Sep 2012). OP just needs to upgrade Maven in order to be compatible with newer SE version  will be considered as the standard answer.

Maven 3.9.5,  pom.xml not add war plugin, will use war:3.4.0:war (default-war). But there is only one standard answer here. You must explicitly add the war plugin and set the specified version number. No other answers will be accepted. Only the answer that matches someone's answer is the standard answer.
